# document-viewer in ionic not working not open file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, documentviewer

Hello  I use followring code not working How to Resole It..

```
 fileTransfer.download(url, path + 'abcd.pdf').then((entry) => {
            let localUrl = entry.toURL();
            const toast = this.toast.create({
              message: 'Download Complted',
              duration: 20000,
              position: 'top',
              closeButtonText: 'OK',
              showCloseButton: true,
            });
            toast.present();
            this.document.viewDocument(localUrl, 'application/pdf', {});
        }, (error) => {
            // handle error
            console.log("In error");
            console.log(error);
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

How to be it working!!

Comment: What kind of issue you are facing ? please add some details related to issue you are getting while using above code.

Comment: Issue is like file downloaded but can't open in documentViewer.. I mean 

            this.document.viewDocument(localUrl, 'application/pdf', {});
 This--> line is not working

Answer (score 1):

Did you add document viewer plugin in you project? please see this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/ you can find commands.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-document-viewer
npm install --save @ionic-native/document-viewer
```

Then you have to pass options also in viewDocument functions

```
      fileTransfer.download(url, path + 'abcd.pdf').then((entry) => {
            let localUrl = entry.toURL();
            const toast = this.toast.create({
              message: 'Download Complted',
              duration: 20000,
              position: 'top',
              closeButtonText: 'OK',
              showCloseButton: true,
            });
            toast.present();
             const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
             title: 'My PDF'
            }
            this.document.viewDocument(localUrl, 'application/pdf', options);
        }, (error) => {
            // handle error
            console.log("In error");
            console.log(error);
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: I did same as above But File Didn't open